# Dimensional interpretation of inverse gradient length $\frac{d}{dx} \ln(Y)$

Tags: dimensional-analysis, differentiation

## Preliminary definition: inverse gradient length

Let me first explain what I mean by  that term. The inverse gradient length of some quantity $Y$ (often thermodynamic temperature $T$) $L_Y^{-1}$ is usually defined as $$L_Y^{-1} = \frac{1}{Y} | \nabla Y |$$ or in a 1D case $$L_Y^{-1} = \frac{1}{Y}\frac{dY}{dx}$$ It usually represents a characterisic length of change of $Y$ which can be seen when the previous equation is rewritten as $$\frac{dY}{dx} = \frac{Y}{L_Y}$$ which under appropriate assumptions has a solution $$Y(x) = \exp\left(\frac{x}{L_Y}\right)$$

## The problem: short form with logarithm

I've often seen it written in the short form $$L_Y^{-1}=\frac{d}{dx}\ln(Y)$$ since **formally** using the chain rule of differentiation it is the same. However, I'm not sure how to interpret the dimension of the short form, because $Y$ often has some physical dimension (e.g. K in the case of $T$) and even if $Y > 0$ (which is the case with $T$) $\ln()$ would somehow have to discard the dimension of $Y$ in order to keep both sides of the equation at the dimension m$^{-1}$.

I've always thought that transcendental functions can accept only non-dimensional numbers, mostly to prevent these issues.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see something like $\ln(X)$ or $\exp(X)$ where $X$ is a dimensionful quantity, whoever wrote that expression was too lazy to carefully state that you are meant to non-dimensionalize $X$ by introducing a scale $X_0$ for it, and replacing $X$ by $X/X_0$.

Now $X/X_0$ is dimensionless, and you can apply $\ln$ or $\exp$ or whatever other function to it. Note that replacing $X\mapsto X/X_0$ in your original formula for $\partial_X\ln(X)$ just cancels the $X_0$, so this indeed gives the same result.